# CLIPS incrementing a variable with a rule

Tags: clips

I want to increment security when the rule is run. Right now it changes nothing. The fact (human_resources n) does exist.

(defglobal ?*security* = 0)

(defrule rule1
    (human_resources n)
    =>
    (defglobal ?*security* = (+ ?*security* 1))
)

This results in ?*security = 1:
(defglobal ?*security* = 0)
(defglobal ?*security* = (+ ?*security* 1))

Answer (score 5):

```
CLIPS> (defglobal ?*security* = 0)
CLIPS> 
(defrule rule1
   (human_resources n)
   =>
   (bind ?*security* (+ ?*security* 1)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> ?*security*
0
CLIPS> (assert (human_resources n))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> ?*security*
1
CLIPS>
```