# How do I add a global variable to count the number of yes or no responses?

Tags: clips, jess

I am working on a nutrition diagnosis system where users are asked questions/symptoms and they respond by entering yes or no. I want to track the count of yes or no and make calculations with them. Like store the count of yes or no in global variables. I already have a function for the calculation but unsure how to capture the yes or no from the user input. I am new to using Jess rules. Below I have added codes of the working rule.

```
(defrule menu::initialize
  (diagnosis)
  =>
  (assert 

  (question (ident q21) (text "Does the child's hair tend to be slight? (Yes or No)") (type yes-no))

  (question (ident q22) (text "Does the child's hair tend to be reddish? (Yes or No)") (type yes-no))

  (question (ident q23) (text "Is the child often affected by ISPA/ TBC? (Yes or No)") (type yes-no))

  (question (ident q24) (text "Does the child's hair tend to be easily falls off? (Yes or No)") (type yes-no))

  (question (ident q25) (text "Is there any abnormality on the child's complexion? (Yes or No)") (type yes-no))

  (question (ident q26) (text "Is there any swelling on the child's face? (Yes or No)") (type yes-no))

  )
  (menu::init)
)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want -- do you want help on *counting* answers, or on actually *getting* the answers, and acting on them?

Comment: @Ernest I want to _count_ the answers.  I have already implemented _getting_ the answers Sir.

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718243/clips-incrementing-a-variable-with-a-rule, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171886/clips-to-count-students-and-prinout-sum, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584478/increment-or-change-variable-each-time-jess-rule-fires, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173106/clips-printout-number-of-times-rule-fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown a rule called "menu::initialize" which inserts some facts called "question". You need a rule to fire on these facts, and this rule would then contain a statement to add 1 to a global variable. You can find examples for rules and for using global variables in the Jess manual.

Please don't expect someone on SO to do your homework for you.

Comment: it is not a homework assignment, it is a project am working on. It's a steep learning curve as I am pretty new to jess. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the suggested solution above and got exactly what I was looking for.

My implementation below:.. Might not be an optimal solution but it works. Thanks SO :D

```
(defrule get-y21
"Add 1 to global variable for every yes answer from question21"
 (answer (ident q21) (text yes ))
=>
(bind ?*countyes* (+ ?*countyes* 1))
)

(defrule get-n21
"Add 1 to global variable for every no answer from question21 "
 (answer (ident q21) (text no ))
=>
(bind ?*countno* (+ ?*countno* 1))
)
```